# C code to count the number of characters, words and lines in a file

Tags: c, file

I am a beginner with C, so I wanted to see a code which consists on counting  the number of characters, words and lines in a given  a file. I found the code below BUT the problem that I didn't understand why we have to increment words and lines for last word after the while loop: `if (characters > 0)...`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    FILE *file;
    char path[100];
    char ch;
    int characters, words, lines;

    /* Input path of files to merge to third file */
    printf("Enter source file path: ");
    scanf("%s", path);

    /* Open source files in 'r' mode */
    file = fopen(path, "r");

    /* Check if file opened successfully */
    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("\nUnable to open file.\n");
        printf("Please check if file exists and you have read privilege.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /*
     * Logic to count characters, words and lines.
     */
    characters = words = lines = 0;
    while ((ch = fgetc(file)) != EOF) {
        characters++;

        /* Check new line */
        if (ch == '\n' || ch == '\0')
            lines++;

        /* Check words */
        if (ch == ' ' || ch == '\t' || ch == '\n' || ch == '\0')
            words++;
    }

    /* Increment words and lines for last word */
    if (characters > 0) {
        words++;
        lines++;
    }

    /* Print file statistics */
    printf("\n");
    printf("Total characters = %d\n", characters);
    printf("Total words      = %d\n", words);
    printf("Total lines      = %d\n", lines);

    /* Close files to release resources */
    fclose(file);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char ch;` -->> `int ch;` (and:you are not counting words, you are counting whitespace characters)

Comment: the goal of having _int ch_ is to be compatible with EOF

Comment: Suppose the input file doesn't end with a newline. Try to use a 3-byte long file containg "foo" (not "foo\n" as usual). *[I say that for that file (3-byte "foo") there are 3 characters, 1 word, and 0 lines; but your program may have another opinion.]*

Comment: *`scanf("%s", path);`* – never use the conversion specifier `%s` without specifying a `width` to limit the number of characters written to the destination. For `char path[100];` use `scanf("%99s", path);` ... 99 + terminating `'\0'` = 100. Also define/declare variables as close as possible to where they're used. And it is `int main(void)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This program has some problems:

- `ch` must be defined as `int` to allow for correct detection of `EOF`.
- overlong input for `scanf("%s", path);` will overflow `path` and cause undefined behavior. Also check the return value to detect invalid input or premature end of file:

  ```
  if (scanf("%99s", path) != 1)
      return 1;
  ```
- testing `ch == '\0'` to count lines is arguable. The standard `wc` unix utility does not consider null bytes to act as line separators.
- `if (ch == ' ' || ch == '\t' || ch == '\n' || ch == '\0')` is also not the standard method for detecting word boundaries. `if (isspace(ch))` is more idiomatic.
- the word count is incorrect: multiple spaces will count as multiple words! You should instead detect boundaries, ie space characters followed by non space characters.
- the last test is a lame attempt at fixing the above problem, it does not suffice. A extra test is indeed needed to count the last last of the stream if the stream does not end with a newline.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    FILE *file;
    char path[1024];
    int ch, last;
    long long int characters, words, lines;

    /* Input path of files to merge to third file */
    printf("Enter source file path: ");
    if (scanf("%255s", path) != 1) {
        printf("Invalid input\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* Open source files in 'r' mode */
    file = fopen(path, "r");

    /* Check if file opened successfully */
    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("Unable to open file %s\n", path);
        printf("Please check if file exists and you have read privilege.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /*
     * Logic to count characters, words and lines.
     */
    characters = words = lines = 0;
    last = '\n';
    while ((ch = fgetc(file)) != EOF) {
        characters++;

        /* Check new line */
        if (ch == '\n')
            lines++;

        /* Check words */
        if (!isspace(ch) && isspace(last))
            words++;

        last = ch;
    }

    /* Increment words and lines for last word */
    if (last != '\n') {
        lines++;
    }

    /* Print file statistics */
    printf("\n");
    printf("Total characters = %lld\n", characters);
    printf("Total words      = %lld\n", words);
    printf("Total lines      = %lld\n", lines);

    /* Close file to release resources */
    fclose(file);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The output will need to be adjusted depending on the input file entered ends with a nice newline ('\n') characters or not.

For a plain sain text file with terminating '\n' on all lines (including the last), remove those increments after the loops.

But it seems the program needs to be debugged a little for these corner cases and it depends on your definition. But I'd highly recommend using the Linux/Unix command `wc` as a reference and tiebreaker.